# Not able to use Custom Cell with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to populate uitableview with custom but getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(style:reuseIdentifier:)' for class 'Appname.PostCellView'
```

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! PostCellView
        return cell
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(PostCellView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Post View Cell: (this class is loaded in the File's Owner of the view)

```
import UIKit
protocol PostCellViewDelegate: class {

}

class PostCellView: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate:  PostCellViewDelegate?


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let _ = commonInitialization()

    }

    func customise(imageName : String , color : UIColor, logoLabelValue : String, websiteValue: String)
    {
    }

    func commonInitialization() -> UIView
    {
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PostCellView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        return view

    }

}
```

Please help me finding what's wrong with my code and how I should rectify the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    // Code
}
```

Please check this [tutorial](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2015/09/uitableviewcell-create-custom-prototype.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please shift the call to `commonInitialization()` from `initWithCoder` to method `awakeFromNib`. Also remove the `initWithCoder` method

In your `PostCellView` code add this method and remove the initWithCoder.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  let _ = commonInitialization()
}
```